# Preserve row height when copying a range with merged cells

Tags: excel, vba

[Inspection templates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gQjO.png)

Depending on which inspection is going to be undertaken I load the inspection sheet (a name defined selection) from Inspection template and add it to a worksheet that contains all the tag information for a selected tag to be inspected

```
Sub copycells()

' copycells Macro
'

'
    Application.Goto Reference:="Ex_d_Visual"
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A9").Select    
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

the problem is that the merged cells height does not copy across to the new worksheet.
"EX_d_Visual" = A1:K41

I have tried many different copy paste options and paste special options but can't seem to get it to work, I think that I may need to use a "for cell next" loop and get each original cell height then set the new sheet equivalent cell to the same height. getting the cell height from the original is doable using the range "Ex_d_Visual" but just not sure how to set the new sheet as I only know the single cell that I have copied into.

Answer (score 0):

### Adjust Row Height in a Copied Range

```vb
Sub CopyCells()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = wb.Names("Ex_d_Visual").RefersToRange
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dws.Range("A9")
    
    srg.Copy dCell
        
    Dim sCell As Range
        
    For Each sCell In srg.Cells
        dCell.RowHeight = sCell.RowHeight
        Set dCell = dCell.Offset(1)
    Next sCell
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi VBasic2008 I have tried your fix but unfortunately this doesn't work with Merged cells

Comment: Hi VBasic2008  unfortunately this doesn't work , I get Run time error "1004" "we can't do this to a merged cell." I have managed to load all the cell heights form the source, into an array, I am now trying to figure out how to unload the array to the new sheet. The array is called Heights the length is to the last                  row  For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        Debug.Print rng.Cells(RowIndex:=i, ColumnIndex:="B").RowHeight
        Heights = Array(rng.Cells(RowIndex:=i, ColumnIndex:="B").RowHeight)
    Next.    Not sure how to set the new sheets row heights.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, since you know that the destination merged range will have the same number of rows in it, you can define it using `.Resize` to be identical in size to the source range.

Then looping over the rows to apply the original row height could look like this:

```vb
Const RangeName = "Ex_d_Visual"
Const SheetName = "Sheet1"
Const RangeAddress = "A9"

Dim SourceRange As Range
Set SourceRange = ThisWorkbook.Names(RangeName).RefersToRange

Dim DestinationRange As Range
Set DestinationRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName).Range(RangeAddress).Resize(SourceRange.Rows.Count, SourceRange.Columns.Count)

Dim Row As Range, Offset As Long
For Each Row In SourceRange.Rows
    DestinationRange.Rows(1 + Offset).RowHeight = Row.Height
    Offset = Offset + 1
Next Row
```

Comment: Hi DecimalTurn this fix works a treat thanks for most of the selected range but for some reason rows are larger than the original Height 33.1 in the new sheet1 and 14.5 in the original and 3 rows didn't get enlarged to the same height as the original, any ideas why this would be

Comment: Sorry DecimalTurn, problem wasn't your code my test sheet had a problem code is working fone now thanks

Comment: @Spectral, I'm glad I could help. If this (or any future answer) solves your issue, please consider accepting it by [clicking the check mark beside it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/372533). This is not an obligation, but it indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: Hi DecimalTurn I will be glade to het the check mark, I have run in to one problem, My code selects the ticksheet depending on the type of protection the example I gave was for one type Ex_d_visual and your code works well but I have 9 templates which are named selection of cells within the sheet  inspection templates. The const RangeName needs to be a variable that I can passed the name into Sub, I have tried changing the const to a variable but then it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: At the moment I have it coping the template into Autogen Inspection  with the following  line: Sheets("Inspection templates").Range(Inspec_TickSht).Copy Sheets("AutoGen Inspection").Range("B20") 'Copies the template to AutoGen Inspection sheet where inspection _TickSht has the named range eg Ex_d_visual. but this has the problem that it doesn't resize the cells

Comment: @Spectral, I think your question was mainly concerned with the issue of copying row height, so it seems to me the new issues you are facing would be better asked about in another question instead of the comment thread. However, regarding your first issue regarding using a *range address* instead of the name of a *named range*, you can always use something like `Set SourceRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SomeSheetName).Range(SomeRangeAddress)`

Comment: Hi DecimalTurn the issues are the same I need to copy the row height from the source range to destination, the reason that I got sidetracked is because your code worked for a set range but my application uses different set ranges. maybe starting a new thread with the full problem may be best. thanks